# How to perform calculation on a for loop jinja template field using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, for-loop, flask, jinja2

I have a list of items that I queried from my database using a for-loop. I want to multiply each item price by its quantity to get a new total price and also get the total price for all items in the for-loop. How can I achieve this using JS?

I followed this example  https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Do-Calculations-Form-Fields-AutoCalc.html but, only the first item in the for loop is working and the other items on the list are all having the same total with the first item

This is a section of my code

```
<form name="cart">
<table class="timetable_sub">
 <thead>
  <tr>

   <th>Product</th>
   <th>Product Name</th>
   <th>Quantity</th>
   <th>Price</th>
   <th>Total</th>
   <th>Remove</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  {% for item in user_cart %}
   <tr class="rem1">    
   <td class="invert">{{item.item_name}}
       </td>
   <td class="invert"><input type="number" name="qty" value=" 
                {{item.quantity}}">     
    </td>
      <td class="invert"><input type="number" name="price" disabled 
      value="{{item.amount}}">
       </td>
   <td class="invert"><input type="text" name="item_total" value="" 
       jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}">
       </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody></table>
<input type="text" name="sub_total" value="" 
     jAutoCalc="SUM({item_total})">
</form>
```

I want to achieve the result in the example https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Do-Calculations-Form-Fields-AutoCalc/ 
but I am getting this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CYl3olVoYk6K-n96zxXpf11B1QWZ7FWA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same `name` for every table row. Append another identifier (such as `loop.index`) so that they are unique:

```
{% for item in user_cart %}
...
<input type="number" name="qty_{{ loop.index }}" value="{{item.quantity}}">
...
<input type="number" name="price_{{ loop.index }}" 
...
<input type="text" name="item_total_{{ loop.index }}" value="" 
       jAutoCalc="{qty_{{ loop.index }}} * {price_{{ loop.index }}}">
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My major challenge now is to send this form to database table since there are multiple form fields with the same `name`